# jquery adding click event to dynamically created element

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, live

i have the need to add a click event to a list item i create dynamically after the DOM has loaded.

I'm using ;

```
$("#ListDiv li").live("click",function(event){
  do something......
 });
```

however when the element is loaded on the page and i click it i get nothing.

This works fine in Firefox but not in IE8. I also tried jquery livequery and deleagte but neither worked. I tried debugging with IE8 developer tools but the method is never reached

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and make sure you bind once the [DOM is ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ListDiv").delegate("li", "click", function (event) {
        // do something
    });
});
```

EDIT:

The above solution, while still perfectly valid, is now legacy/deprecated. jQuery has since introduced the [`.on() method`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required
>   for attaching event handlers.

The implementation is quite similar to the `.delegate` solution posted above, but be aware that the order of parameters has changed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ListDiv").on("click", "li", function (event) {
        // do something
    });
});
```

Comment: @cliveholloway - Thank you for pointing that out. I have just updated the answer :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

push your code inside document.ready

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#ListDiv li").live("click",function(event){
        do something......
       });
     });
```